# In which countries are there organised Messier Marathons?

Tags: amateur-observing, messier-catalog, observation-campaign

Just out of curiosity...

In which countries have there been or are current, organised [Messier Marathons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_marathon)?

Thank you for all answers and effort for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I have researched, there are really many countries that organize Messier Marathon, but also many astronomers organize it locally only for them and don't publish it on web, so I could write here nearly every country.